# Using Python, how do I compare many strings (in one file) on equality?

Tags: python, text, facet

In a .txt file are more than 10k records and in each line is exactly one checksum, which is duplicated sometimes.
The goal is to write code to seek out 1. the count of each duplicated checksum 2. and the lines of occurrences of each duplicated record.

The result should be looking like:
"4d2da647[..]": Total Counts 42 ; In Lines {5,21,432,3424, 11679, [...]}
..
.

I do not have much experience with coding yet, and I am not asking anyone for doing all the work. But looking up the internet, I did not find similar cases and do not know how to orientate.

I started with:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as obj:
    lines_list = obj.readlines

# compare lines on equality

# print out total count of duplettes and occurrences in lines
```

For any guiding information, I would appreciate that very much. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is basically create a [python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)(key-value pair) with the keys being your checksums and count being the value.

```py
checksum_dict = {}

for line in lines_list:
    if line in checksum_dict:
        checksum_dict[line] += 1
    else:
        checksum_dict[line] = 1
```

Now you have the count of all checksums in this dict and you can easily output the information you need from here.

From your output example, you also need the linenumbers to be stored, so instead of having a simple count you can store a list for every checksum and add the line numbers to that list.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot because now it is clear to me how the process is called with its' own terms and I can work on the needed output of information from here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the line numbers and the count of lines, you may be able to use the following. This is sorted from the largest amount of dups to the least.

```
chksums = dict()

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(file): # here, line numbers begin with 0, not 1
        #chksums.setdefault(line.strip(), []).append(line_num)
        # these 5 lines do what the 1 line above does
        line = line.strip()
        if line in chksums:
            chksums[line].append(line_num)
        else:
            chksums[line] = [line_num]

for line in sorted(chksums, key=lambda x: len(chksums[x]), reverse = True):
    print(line, f'Total Counts: {len(chksums[line])}, ',
          'line number(s)', ','.join(map(str,chksums[line])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is much appreciated!